# Pegando o ID do DataTable Server-side

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

Estou usando o **[DataTable Server-side](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)**, mas não estou sabendo como pegar o `ID` da minha tabela para poder abrir as páginas de editar e excluir.

**server-side**

```
$table = 'financ_receita';

$primaryKey = 'ID_Receita';

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'ID_Receita',    'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'nome',          'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'valor',         'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'dataVenci',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'formaEntrada',  'dt' => 4 ),

);
```

Montagem da tabela

```
var myTable =
  $('#dynamic-table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "dados.php",
    "columns": [{
        "bVisible": false,
        "bSortable": false
      },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      {
        data: null,
        className: "center",
        defaultContent: '<a href="editar?id=" class="editor_edit button blue">Editar</a> <a href="excluir?id=" class="editor_remove button red">Del</a>',
        orderable: false,
        bSearchable: false,
      }
    ],
    "language": {
      "url": "/assets/js/dataTables/lang/pt-br.json"
    },
  });
```

Gostaria de colocar o **ID_Receita** nos respectivos links: `editar?id=` e `excluir?id=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para elementos dinâmicos, use `render` em vez de `defaultContent`:

```
render: function(data){
   return '<a href="editar?id='+data[0]+'" class="editor_edit button blue">Editar</a> <a href="excluir?id='+data[0]+'" class="editor_remove button red">Del</a>'
},
```

O valor em `data[0]` representa o dado da primeira coluna, ou seja, o `ID_Receita`.

Veja o que diz a [documentação](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) referente ao `defaultContent`:

> *This option is available for those use cases - creating static content
>   for a column. If you wish to create dynamic content (i.e. based on
>   other data in the row), the `columns.render` option should be used.*

Tradução livre:

> Esta opção é disponível para casos onde o conteúdo é estático. Se
>   deseja criar conteúdos dinâmicos (ou seja, baseado em outro dado da
>   linha da tabela), a opção `columns.render` deve ser usada.

Comment: Bom dia Sam. Como faço para que o `render` ler a função `onClick="return false;"`. `'<a href="financeiroContaAreceberEpagar.php?id='+data[0]+'&i=3d" class="btn-link no-border red delete-event" data-title="Apagar" data-content="Deseja apagar esse lançamento?" onClick="return false;"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i></a>' +`

Comment: Estou organizando dessa forma https://prnt.sc/o4uay4

Comment: Bom dia. Não entendi bem a função do onclick. Vc quer que anular o redirecionamento do link?

Comment: Como os dados estão vindo via ajax, e usando o `render` para exibir os controle de Ver, Editar e Excluir, parece que o `return` do `render` esta anulando a minha `onClick="return false;"`, essa função apenas abre o modal perguntando se realmente quer apagar.

Comment: No botão editar, tenho uma class chamada `link` onde ela é apenas para identificar esse outra função `$(".link").mouseover(function(){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $('.iframe').attr('src', href)
        });` que passa o href para dentro do `src` do iframe, para que o modal abra a página. Por algum motivo tambem não reconhece.

Comment: Faça assim: `$(document).on("mouseover", ".link", function(){`

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado Sam